# Best way to save SXSSFWorkbook to blob?

Tags: java, excel, hibernate, apache-poi, java-io

I'm using Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook to generate a .xlsx excel spreadsheet, but instead of downloading it I need to save that file into a blob. I also need this to be able to scale up, so if I have 600,000+ records put into the file, I need to avoid the out of memory error. Here's the code

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
addContent();
```

Usually when output to a file I do something like

```
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
workbook.write(output);
```

But in this case I don't need it to go to a file, just into a blob on the database, except there's no way to save SXSSFWorkbook into a blob. I could save the workbook into OutputStream and try to save that into a blob, but usually you need inputStream instead. Is there a utility to turn outputStream into inputStream?

Comment: not sure how blobs are handled in hibernate, but at least the standard blob api provides you with a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBinaryStream(long))

Comment: Why not write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` then call `getBytes()` and pass those to the database?

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream` puts everything in memory, so big files might not work.

Comment: @kiwiwings that could probably work if I already have a blob, but I only have a workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I end up putting it to a file and then read from it.

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
workbook.write(output);
workbook.dispose();
output.flush();
output.close();

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
Blob blob = dao.saveInputStreamToBlob(input);
```

then in the DAO using hibernate session to getLobHelper and create the blob from the inputStream. Performance is ok, I only tested to 25,000 or so records but no memory issues yet.

Answer (score 2):

Using the advice from @kiwiwings i have the following working:

```
Blob binario = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(new byte[0]);
SXSSFWorkbook excel = ...
excel.write(binario.setBinaryStream(0));
```

And that's it.